# how to securely expose the API address for ipfs cluster services?

Tags: ipfs

I implemented the following from the docs and this all works but the API access is set 0.0.0.0 which is a security hole allowing people from outside the network to connect and add files. I want to create a private network and hence secure the network by allowing just localhost on the API access or access from a known server. But then I find the peers themselves do not connect. Is there a solution for this?

version: '3.4'

```
# This is an example docker-compose file to quickly test an IPFS Cluster
# with multiple peers on a contained environment.

# It runs 3 cluster peers (cluster0, cluster1...) attached to go-ipfs daemons
# (ipfs0, ipfs1...) using the CRDT consensus component. Cluster peers
# autodiscover themselves using mDNS on the docker internal network.
#
# To interact with the cluster use "ipfs-cluster-ctl" (the cluster0 API port is
# exposed to the locahost. You can also "docker exec -ti cluster0 sh" and run
# it from the container. "ipfs-cluster-ctl peers ls" should show all 3 peers a few
# seconds after start.
#
# For persistance, a "compose" folder is created and used to store configurations
# and states. This can be used to edit configurations in subsequent runs. It looks
# as follows:
#
# compose/
# |-- cluster0
# |-- cluster1
# |-- ...
# |-- ipfs0
# |-- ipfs1
# |-- ...
# 
# During the first start, default configurations are created for all peers.

services:

##################################################################################
## Cluster PEER 0 ################################################################
##################################################################################

  ipfs0:
    container_name: ipfs0
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:release
#   ports:
#     - "4001:4001" # ipfs swarm - expose if needed/wanted
#     - "5001:5001" # ipfs api - expose if needed/wanted
#     - "8080:8080" # ipfs gateway - expose if needed/wanted
    volumes:
      - ./compose/ipfs0:/data/ipfs

  cluster0:
    container_name: cluster0
    image: ipfs/ipfs-cluster:latest
    depends_on:
      - ipfs0
    environment:
      CLUSTER_PEERNAME: cluster0
      CLUSTER_SECRET: ${CLUSTER_SECRET} # From shell variable if set
      CLUSTER_IPFSHTTP_NODEMULTIADDRESS: /dns4/ipfs0/tcp/5001
      CLUSTER_CRDT_TRUSTEDPEERS: '*' # Trust all peers in Cluster
      CLUSTER_RESTAPI_HTTPLISTENMULTIADDRESS: /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/9094 # Expose API
      CLUSTER_MONITORPINGINTERVAL: 2s # Speed up peer discovery
    ports:
          # Open API port (allows ipfs-cluster-ctl usage on host)
          - "127.0.0.1:9094:9094"
          # The cluster swarm port would need  to be exposed if this container
          # was to connect to cluster peers on other hosts.
          # But this is just a testing cluster.
          # - "9096:9096" # Cluster IPFS Proxy endpoint
    volumes:
      - ./compose/cluster0:/data/ipfs-cluster

##################################################################################
## Cluster PEER 1 ################################################################
##################################################################################

# See Cluster PEER 0 for comments (all removed here and below)
  ipfs1:
    container_name: ipfs1
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:release
    volumes:
      - ./compose/ipfs1:/data/ipfs

  cluster1:
    container_name: cluster1
    image: ipfs/ipfs-cluster:latest
    depends_on:
      - ipfs1
    environment:
      CLUSTER_PEERNAME: cluster1
      CLUSTER_SECRET: ${CLUSTER_SECRET}
      CLUSTER_IPFSHTTP_NODEMULTIADDRESS: /dns4/ipfs1/tcp/5001
      CLUSTER_CRDT_TRUSTEDPEERS: '*'
      CLUSTER_MONITORPINGINTERVAL: 2s # Speed up peer discovery
    volumes:
      - ./compose/cluster1:/data/ipfs-cluster

##################################################################################
## Cluster PEER 2 ################################################################
##################################################################################

# See Cluster PEER 0 for comments (all removed here and below)
  ipfs2:
    container_name: ipfs2
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:release
    volumes:
      - ./compose/ipfs2:/data/ipfs

  cluster2:
    container_name: cluster2
    image: ipfs/ipfs-cluster:latest
    depends_on:
      - ipfs2
    environment:
      CLUSTER_PEERNAME: cluster2
      CLUSTER_SECRET: ${CLUSTER_SECRET}
      CLUSTER_IPFSHTTP_NODEMULTIADDRESS: /dns4/ipfs2/tcp/5001
      CLUSTER_CRDT_TRUSTEDPEERS: '*'
      CLUSTER_MONITORPINGINTERVAL: 2s # Speed up peer discovery
    volumes:
      - ./compose/cluster2:/data/ipfs-cluster

# For adding more peers, copy PEER 1 and rename things to ipfs2, cluster2.
# Keep bootstrapping to cluster0.
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create the [private network](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/experimental-features.md#private-networks) in IPFS, this allow your ipfs nodes connect to ipfs nodes that have the same swarm key.

In you ipfs0 and ipfs1 services, you need to add two new enviroments variables, and a new volume:

```
ipfs0:
    container_name: ipfs0
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:release
#   ports:
#     - "4001:4001" # ipfs swarm - expose if needed/wanted
#     - "5001:5001" # ipfs api - expose if needed/wanted
#     - "8080:8080" # ipfs gateway - expose if needed/wanted
environment:
      - LIBP2P_FORCE_PNET=1
      - IPFS_SWARM_KEY_FILE=/data/ipfs/swarm.key
    volumes:
      - ./compose/ipfs0:/data/ipfs
      - ./swarm.key:/data/ipfs/swarm.key
```

To generate the swarm.key check this [link](https://github.com/Kubuxu/go-ipfs-swarm-key-gen). The swarm.key must be in your ipfs root path (For default, ~/.ipfs, in the container ipfs path is: **/data/ipfs**). This swarm.key should be the same for all ipfs nodes.

For IPFS Cluster, you have it good, with this command you can generate you cluster key:

```
export CLUSTER_SECRET=$(od  -vN 32 -An -tx1 /dev/urandom | tr -d ' \n')
```

I recommend you to add files using ipfs cluster REST Api. [Check this link](https://cluster.ipfs.io/documentation/reference/configuration/) to configure ipfs cluster and make more secure to upload files (Using the api secret key), or you can only allow localhost as a ipfs cluster network:

```
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:9094:9094" # Only open the port 9094 in localhost
```